# unable to retrieve the passed value from jsp to controller using url via a button

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I am assigning href to a button and passing a value to the controller

1. JSP page

   ```
   <td><a href="viewController?book_id=<%=vo.getBookId()%>"><input type="button" name="remove" value="DELETE"/></a>
   </td>
   ```
2. In controller, I am trying to get the value when the button is clicked using:

   ```
   if(request.getParameter("remove") !=null)
   {
       int cart_id=(Integer)request.getSession(false).getAttribute("cartid");
       b_id = (String) request.getParameter("book_id");
       int bid=Integer.parseInt(b_id);
       System.out.println(bid);
   }
   ```

This prints a null value though I have passed `book_id` value in the URL.
I want to know how can I get the value passed in the URL via the button.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't combine [a] tag with an [input] tag like that.
Try using a form instead with hidden inputs:

```html
<form action=viewController>
<input type=hidden name=remove value=delete>
<input type=hidden name=book_id value=<%=vo.getBookId()%>>
<input type=submit value='Delete'>
</form>
```

The resulting url will be : `viewController?remove=delete&book_id=...`

Comment: first of all thanks as this works ... But I am still confused at what is the reason why cannot I use URL rewriting with a button?

Comment: buttons by themselves do nothing.  You need to add javascript code with an onclick="..." to make a button do something.

Answer (score 2):

When submit button is pressed, the entire form will be sent. You can select where data will be sent by using attribute `action`:

```html
<form action="demo_form.jsp"> 
  <!--inputs here-->
  <input type="submit">Send me now</input>
</form>
```

In that case form will be sent to demo_form.jsp. In HTML5 you can use [formaction](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_button_formaction.asp) attribute if you want use different servlets for different buttons

Any way, you shouldn't use links for sending forms.

It is possible to use links **without** button:

```html
<a href="viewController?book_id=<%=vo.getBookId()%>">Remove</a>
```